Paginated Report B. - Not selecting all the values from a dropdown
I want to update a parameter based on Customer Group where selecting a Customer Group should automatically select all the items of the Customer Subgroup, and Customer parameter's dropdown. Image for reference
Currently, we have to manually select all the items of the Customer and Customer Subgroup whereas it ideally should select all the items of the Customer and Customer Subgroup automatically as soon as we click a Customer Group from the Customer Group
I'm using semantic model to populate the parameter values at the moment.
Hope you all can get what I need.

How are you populating the parameter values at the moment? From a SQL Query?

using a semantic model

The term you are looking for is "Cascading Parameters". Most of the examples  are based around simple SQL Queries but take a look at this it may help. https://youtu.be/6KBnUkw6UBg
